# How to trigger the google chrome website translation popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Morning yall,
I´m currently trying to get the google chrome in build browser translation system to work.

I added the `lang=de` attribute to my html tag and included some text in another language.
However I still need to do right click and then click on translate in order for chrome to translate the page.

[image: Image of my local page not showing the popup]

However on pages like paris.fr there is a google translate popup that activates automaticly.

[image: Image of paris.fr google translation popup]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because of the `lang="de"` meta, it's not bothering to look for other languages (and it looks like your settings are to offer to translate *non*-German languages to German), but I think that is unlikely since [according to Google documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1), they don't use the `lang` attribute, and using a single language is the best way to help detect page language.

You could use the [Google Translate API](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/google-translate-translateelement-part-of-page-with-code-examples.html) and add extra buttons or something to offer the translation, if you're willing to either do some extra work figuring how to detect user's language preferences (maybe using something like [`Navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language)) or always showing [Google Translate button/drop-down](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp) near that section regardless of user preferences.